# Destroy or Reset singleton Realm Repo after logout?

Tags: swift, realm, mongodb-atlas, realm-mobile-platform

I use my Realm repo as a singleton class all over my views.

I use the repo like:

```
var repo = SingletonRepo.shared
```

The singleton class:

```
class SingletonRepo{
    static let shared = RealmRepo()
    
    private init() { }
}
```

Everything works fine until a logout and re-login happens. The realm syncs get inactive.

This happens, I think, because the singleton does not get reseted/destroyed on the re-login.

What is the best way to solve this problem? Destroy or Reset the repo? Where should I do that? In the login method or at the logout?

Also how I can do this on the same singleton class? Create a method reset/delete repo?

***I ve solved this by:***

Adding a reset method to the singleton:

```
class SingletonRepo{
    static var shared = RealmRepo()
    
    private init() { }
    
    static func reset() {
            shared = RealmRepo()
        }
    }
```

And I call the reset method on the logout:

```
func doLogout(){

        repo.doLogout(token: myFCMToken){error in
            SingletonRepo.reset()
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isLogin")
            isLoginShown = true
        }
        
    }
```

Also, I still only use the repo like this:

```
var repo = SingletonRepo.shared
```

I tested and it works, but is this a good solution?

Comment: That's the cost of having a singleton anti-pattern. Instead make it an instance property of something that represents a "logged in user", so it's destroyed when user is logged out.

Comment: Could you please you make an example, I am new at Swift, I appreciate if so

Comment: I added a solution, let me know your opinion on that

Comment: Using static for variables that have the associated state (e.g. whether user is logged in in your case) is another anti-pattern (if you google "static anti-pattern" you will see a lot of explanations why). Follow what person below suggested to you: have a `User` expressed as an object. That object has property `RealmRepo`. When user logs in, you create the object and initialize its property. When user logs out, the associated `User` object is destroyed, and so is its properties.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Realm; it has to do with using a singleton pattern. The core issue is how Realm Sync is implemented *within the singleton* but that code was omitted from the question (which is why it has nothing to do with Realm). Logging in and out will not behave like you've described with proper implementation. Also, as a side note, UserDefaults should not be used in that fashion; it's designed to store User preferences; background color, orientation or widget placement for example. A users logging status is directly handled by Realm so that code is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution can be you can create realm repo based on user logged in, I mean totally user centric repo.

Like:

```
   class LoginUser {
      var realmRepo:RealmRepo = RealmRepo()
   }

   class RealmRepo {
   }
```

After user login create a user instance  Like:  let user = LoginUser()

Now access RealmRepo Like this way: let repo = user.realmRepo

Now use this repo for all your purpose

When user log out simply make the user nil, like: user = nil

by setting nil to logged in user will also discard/destroy your repo too

So this way for every new user, new instance of realmRepo will be created and after log out when you set user=nil repo will be discarded.

And I hope this way your sync issue will be fixed too

Comment: I added a solution, let me know your opinion on that

Comment: @dhaval123 As it works, just make sure before resetting, make a sync with your current singleton class with server so that no data loss happens.

Comment: you mean to call `realm.syncSession.uploadAllLocalChanges()` before the logout?

Comment: IMO, while this is a great answer, it's doesn't solve the actual issue because the question is unclear. The core problem is how Realm Sync is implemented within the singleton and that code was omitted from the question. So the end result is a temporary fix, but doesn't address the root cause. More info and code is needed in the question to actually understand the problem Just .02

Comment: Also, Realm fully supports authentication and knows the users log status and who the current user is, so there's no reason to nil the current user. Many mobile devices don't have multiple users, just one, so to facilitate logging back in (as mentioned in the question) Realm remembers the current user, so nil'ing it is generally not needed.

Comment: @dhaval123 yeah based on your code base just make sure sync all local changes with server, before resetting.